# Is there a method in / on OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider that is called every time the User hits the webserver?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC OWIN website that uses a `CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` middleware in it's HTTP pipeline.

That's interacting with an OAuth cookie to maintain the login session.

I was under the broad impression that `ValidateClientAuthentication` was supposed to get hit every time the user hits the webserver to get a new page, to check the cookie was valid ... but putting a debug point in there and running the site ... didn't hit that.

Is there a method on that class that *does* get hit every time, which I can use to intercept some of that checking?

Comment: Or alternatively, if someone wants to say "no" `ValidateClientAuthentication()` really _should_ be being called on every Controller hit ... then I'll go back and re-check my testing :sweat-grin: